# Parameter estimation for normal distribution in Java

Tags: estimation, normal-distribution, java

Given a set of data (~5000 values) I'd like to draw random samples from the same distribution as the original data. The problem is there is no way to know for sure what distribution the original data comes from.

It makes sense to use normal distribution in my case, although I'd like to be able to motivate that decision, and of course I also need to estimate the $(\mu,\sigma)$ pair.

Any idea on how to accomplish this, preferably within Java environment. I have been using [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/NormalDistributionImpl.html) and recently stumbled upon [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) library. I was hoping to get it done without bothering with MATLAB and R.

Comment: you should mention java environment in the title of your question this will maximize the chance to get an answer. Also is there a tag "java" ?

Comment: @robin Yes it is.

Comment: @mbq: cheers! I wasnt too sure about tagging/mentioning java too much; my interest is primarily if it can be done relatively easily, then a Java implementation. But this works as well.

Comment: @posdef, if it is normal, then simulation is [easy](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/random/Normal.html), just calculate [mean](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#mean(cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList)) and standard deviation. For motivation you will need to [test](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/jmsl/v40/api/com/imsl/stat/NormalityTest.html) whether the sample is normal.

Comment: @mpiktas: thanks for your reply, although I am not quite sure why you chose to comment instead of answering :) As you have mentioned, sampling is no problem but I need to test normality. It seems like the library you've mentioned is commercial though. Could I just do a $\chi^2$ test, or would I need to implement a Shapirov-Wilk, alternatively Lilliefors, test on my own?

Comment: @posdef, answers require better quality than comments, this is why I commented. As for commercial use, try google to find non comercial. [This seems free](http://www.numericalmethod.info/javadoc/suanshu/basic/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/stats/test/distribution/normality/ShapiroWilk.html). In worst case scenario you will need to reimplement this test, or another normality test. I suggest asking here or on stackoverflow , which of the normality tests is easiest to implement.

Answer (score 4):

How big are the samples that you need? If substantially smaller than the 5000 points you have, say maximum 100 points or so, you could just take a random subset of your sample. Then you don't even need to assume normality - it's guaranteed to come from the distribution you want!

Otherwise, it seems that the `org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive.moment` package has a [Mean](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/moment/Mean.html) and [StandardDeviation](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/moment/StandardDeviation.html) class which use the correct formulas. These should give you $\mu$ and $\sigma$, respectively.

Comment: unfortunately I need to create samples as large as the original dataset, plus I need to do this process a large number of times... So picking random values doesn't seem like a viable option in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the empirical cumulative distribution function (ecdf). With this, you can generate random variables with uniform distribution and map them to your ecdf. This way, you will generate samples with the desired distribution.

In Java, using Colt, you have the class [Empirical](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/random/Empirical.html), where is written:

> **Implementation**: A uniform random number is generated using a user
>   supplied generator. The uniform number is then transformed to the
>   user's distribution using the cumulative probability distribution
>   constructed from the pdf. The cumulative distribution is inverted
>   using a binary search for the nearest bin boundary.